# VBA Looping through different worksheets and pasting rows into master worksheet if condition is met

Tags: vba, loops, conditional-formatting, worksheet

I would like to create VBA code for a command button that does the following:
1. Loops through all worksheets except master worksheet (SOLD)
2. Copies rows if condition is met (Paid)
3. Pastes rows to Master worksheet (Sold)

So far I have the code but my problem is that it loops through all worksheets including master worksheet (i.e duplicates information in master worksheet) and if I try to write for If ws.name<>"Sold" then The code stops working giving message box error .  Please help me modify the code.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

Dim i, LastRow

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
If ws.Cells(i, "M").Value = "Paid" Then
ws.Cells(i, "M").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sold").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
Next i
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you put the IF statement, but it must work in this way:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i, LastRow

For Each ws In Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "Sold" Then
    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If ws.Cells(i, "M").Value = "Paid" Then
         ws.Cells(i, "M").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sold").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End If
    Next i
End If

Next ws
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Worked perfectly.

Comment: @pharzandinc, Please mark this answer as accepted. It shows other people that the question is solved and gives the person who answered some credit. Take care :) [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @wizhi thank you for telling me this, I was looking at marking it as responded but didn't see anything so left it as is until you have mentioned it